# leaflet GeoJSON value not variable name

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have a GeoJSON file that has fields of the days of the week like "Monday" with values 'Y' or 'N'. So I want to get today's day value, using something like

`var theDayValue = 'feature.properties + day'`

However this gives me a string. I want to get the value of

`var theDayValue = feature.properties.Monday`.

I plan on using this to show if open or closed in Leaflet by symbol color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using bracket notation instead of dot notation... you just have to give it the property name as a string (i.e., `var theDayValue = feature.properties['Monday']`). 
Assuming that 'day' is a variable whose value is the string matching the name of the field you want, that would look like this:

```
var day = 'Monday';
var theDayValue = feature.properties[day];
```