# Leaflet: calling a JS variable after feature.properties

Tags: arcgis-desktop, leaflet, javascript

Currently I have a dictionary where each field from my geoJSON is listed as a key and its alias is the value. I want to loop through this dictionary and return feature.properties.key. Here's some sample code:

```
var watershedFields = {Shed_Scale: "Watershed Scale", TP_TMDL: "TP TMDL"};

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = "<b>" + feature.properties.Location + " Watershed</b> 
    <br>"
    for(var field in watershedFields) {
        var fieldName = watershedFields[field];
        popupContent += "<p>" + fieldName + ": " + feature.properties.field 
        + "<p> <br>"
    }
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}
```

What happens when this runs is that the code looks for a field name in my geoJSON that's labelled "field", and because this doesn't exist, it returns undefined. Basically, I'm wondering if there is a way to call a variable in place of a field name after feature.properties.

Comment: This may be related? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281347/leaflet-geojson-value-not-variable-name/281348#281348